# tabstackengine repeat the endnotes many times

Tags: endnotes, enotez

When I use an `\endnote` command from `enotez` package inside a `tabstackengine` package’s table, the endnote apear as if I call it many times.

### The MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}


\begin{document}

\tabbedCenterstack{
foo \endnote{bar} & baz
}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

### The rendering

[image: end notes appear many times]

As you see, the note appear in the Notes section tree times when I call it just once. I think its because `\tabbedCenterstack` process tree tree times, then the note is tree times loaded.

### Finaly

So how can I avoid to get tree times the endnote?

Comment: The `stackengine` package was just updated this week, to prevent this behavior.  You can download the revision sty file at https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine.  If there is still a problem, let me know.  Alternatively, you can save the offending code in a temporary box and pass the box to the stack.

Comment: I see in the `tabstackengine.sty` he require `stackengine`, so I download the last `stackengine` package in my working directory. But how can I tell LaTeX to use the local directory `stackengine.sty` when it’s called by `stackengine` instead of the system wide `stackengine.sty`?

Comment: If the newer version is in the working directory, it will use that.  Otherwise, you have to update the package that is used by your TeX installation, either manually or using the update facilities of your installation.  For MikTeX, for example, the MikTeX Console performs this task.

Comment: Ok, for the moment the method you give with `\sbox4` work for me. But, as you ask for reviews, so I use TeXlive and when I put the updated `stackengine.sty` in my working directory, it didn’t fix the problem. I don’t know if it’s TeXlive related.

Comment: I believe `tabstackengine` itself is also setting content more than once.  I am looking at this now, but I am guessing I may not be able to eliminate it, based on the technique required to align things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the approach of saving the end note in a temp box first and passing that to the stack.  While I have upgraded `stackengine` to avoid setting the content (internally) more than once, I will have to re-examine `tabstackengine`.  It may not be possible to eliminate the multiple passes, based on the technique used to align all the content.

In any event, this temporary box approach should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}


\begin{document}

\sbox4{\endnote{bar}}
\tabbedCenterstack{
foo\copy4 & baz
}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are worried about using temporary boxes, or if there is more than one endnote in the stack, you can use `\savestack`, which itself creates a unique named box for storing its contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}

\savestack\tmpA{\endnote{bar}}
\savestack\tmpB{\endnote{barr}}
\tabbedCenterstack{
foo\tmpA & baz\tmpB
}

\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

UPDATE: I can confirm that `tabstackengine` itself is setting cell content thrice, as part of its technique of measuring and aligning the content.  I can easily get that down to twice (and will update the package); however, it will be tough to eliminate the two typesets...once for measuring and the other for final typeset.

Comment: Great, still a smart fix, hacky but smart :D But I wonder if it will still work in a LaTeX updated installation.

Comment: I am getting this behavior with `tabstackengine` 2018/03/05 (V2.10) and `stackengine` 2021/07/15 v4.1. <--THE LATEST VERSION